# I have a table of Histogram values and I need to do a P95 calculation and I don't know how to express this in SQL

Tags: postgresql, query

I hope this is an ok place to be asking this.

The table is tracking aggregated API response times essentially by storing the bars of histograms of the times for each API and day.

I need to use this to estimate P95 values for different slices of the API over different time periods. I have that working in Excel but don't know how to convert it to SQL.

I want it in SQL so I can get it into our BI system, the current Excel based solution takes a couple of minutes of manual work for each update which is not conductive to exploration.

The table has the following main columns:

- date - the date the histogram was for
- bucket_start_ms, bucket_size_ms and bucket_end_ms (integers) - identifying the horizontal position and width of the bars (an important detail is all the histograms use the same bucketing scheme and there are never overlapping buckets)
- count (integer) - identifying the height of the bars
- a bunch of columns identifying the APIs in a variety of ways
- total_seconds, sum_square_seconds and average_seconds (floats)

My current Excel based P95 calculation takes a dump from the DB, filtered to the slice I'm interested in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "apm_histogrambucket"."bucket_end_ms",
                "apm_histogrambucket"."date",
                SUM("apm_histogrambucket"."count") AS "ddb_count_sum"
FROM "apm_histogrambucket"
GROUP BY "apm_histogrambucket"."bucket_end_ms",
         "apm_histogrambucket"."date"
```

Think of this as a table with bucket_end_ms as col titles and date as row  titles.

Next we do a cumulative sum left to right.

Then we divide that by the total for the row to get a cumulative percent.

Then for each row we find the smallest cumulative pct that is > 0.95.

And finally we do a linear interpolation based on the cumulative pct's between that columns bucket_end_ms and the bucket_end_ms of the column before it (equiv to the bucket_start_ms of the same column) to get the P95 for the row.

I have no idea how to tackle this in SQL. I think I could get to the cumulative percent, but pulling out the matching column and interpolating is a bit beyond me.

This is on Postgres.

Comment: A `CREATE TABLE` script is the canonical form to present a table definition. It's a pain to reverse-engineer this from creative prose. Please provide a minimal data set and the expected result. Ideally, add a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) to work with. And *always* disclose your version of Postgres. Also, the `DISTINCT` in your query makes no sense.

Comment: The query was lifted from a BI system that loves to put distinct on things,